# Symfony2 customize buttons

Tags: forms, symfony, button

I want to remove `<div>` element arround `<button>` in Symfony2.
My question is: how can I customize the button in Symfony2?

Comment: your question is very ambiguous

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The twig block wrapping the `div` around the buttons is named `button_row`.

It defaults to:

```
{% block button_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock button_row %}
```

Have a look at [Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) aka the default form theme for the twig engine.

Just override the block `button_row` in your template or globally.

You will find all necessary information on how to override forms in the documentation chapter [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create

```
/app/Resources/views/form_custom.html.twig
```

---

```
///app/Resources/views/form_custom.html.twig

{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block button_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock button_row %}
```

---

config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - '::form_custom.html.twig'
```

---

All form render without `<div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can render a form by hand and customize every little detail.

I render my forms like this. (stripped version for easier reading)

```
<form id="new-request"
      action="{{ path('request_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_row(form.data_one) }}
        {{ form_row(form.data_two) }}

        {{ form_row(form._token) }}

        <button type="submit">
            Save
        </button>

        <a href="{{ path('request_index') }}">
           Cancel
        </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe he wants use submit button http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html